# Have Browser Cache S3 pre-signed URLs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, caching

I have a page on an app that downloads "attachments" of a Parent Document onLoad from S3. So - onLoad, a Server call is made to create S3 Pre-Signed URLs and then return them to the client.

These attachment urls will mostly be pictures, pdfs, etc..

These can then be displayed in `img` tags. The user can click through links and an `img` preview in a div will be changed dynamically using jQuery. The pre-signed urls are currently set to the default expiration time of 900s as per the S3 SDK. This is fine.

Currently, this pattern would regenerate new pre-signed links upon refreshing the page (even if under 900s).

My concern is that I'm not sure if Chrome is caching the images. Upon clicking through links and Dev Tools open, I'm seeing that it looks like a Network req to DL the image is happening every time. The header is 200 instead of 304 and I'm seeing that the Request Header's `Cache-Control` is set to 'no-cache'

I've read that the browser will still cache the image even though it may appear that a new request is happening every time. Oddly enough, I've left a tab open for over 900s and the image still appeared.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ugh...I had `disable cache` checked off in DevTools.